# Show button when input type text, checkbox, radio and select tag are compiled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a big help with this community to achieve on show a "next" button when some input tag are compiled.
I've used this code:

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {
    $('#next1').toggle(this.value != '');
});

#next1 {
    display: none;
}
```

But how can I modify it if in my page is more complex?

For example here i have some checkbox, radio input and select tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="name" type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="internet" value='Y'>Y</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="internet" value='N'>N</label>
    <label for="degree">Degree</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="degree" value="degree"> Degree
<select id='city' name='city' title='City' class='required1Sel form-control' >
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='1'>NY</option>
    <option value='2'>LA</option>
    <option value='3'>MIAMI</option>
</select>
    <div id="next1">
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
```

Comment: so you want the next button to be visible only if all the controls have values...right??

Comment: only if all controls have values except "phone".
i have more fields, but not all are required.

Answer (score 0):

For the Select or the Checkbox you can use the [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function.

```
$('#city').change(function() {
    $('#next1').toggle(this.value != '');
});
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpwo8e7e/1/

Comment: it's work, but if i have more select tag and i use a class (required1Sel like the example) it shows me next button while i compiled only one of this.

i've tried with this code

$('.required1Sel').each(function() {
  $('.required1Sel').change(function() {
   $('#next').toggle(this.value != '');
  });    
 });

Comment: You need to put 'flags' for each input. onchange( var changed1 = true). If (changed1 & changed2 & changed 3...) then showbutton. Or maybe you can check if values are not equal to ' '